# Inserting and invalid geometry PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have created a function that runs some validity checks on tables/views in postgres/postgis. Postgres 9.6.11 and PostGIS 2.3. I now need to test this function so I need create a table with an invalid geometry in it. Preferable one that can be corrected with `ST_MakeValid` and one that wouldn't be corrected by that, so I can test all use cases. How does one insert an invalid geometry into a postgis table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a simple task and it is very version dependent.

You can try to brake a valid geometry, or you can try to insert an invalid one.

For example, this line creates an invalid line (2 points, start = end point)

```sql
SELECT st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(480 270,480 270)'),3857);
```

`ST_MakeValid` will transform it to a point.

or create a self intersecting polygon

```sql
SELECT st_isValid('polygon((0 0, 1 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))'::geometry);
NOTICE:  Self-intersection at or near point 0.5 0.5
 st_isvalid
------------
 f
```

`ST_MakeValid` will transform it to a multipolygon

You can also find more sample cases [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/regress/core/isvaliddetail.sql)

Comment: This worked perfectly. The bow tie failed (cause the column only permitted polygons) and the twisted polygon worked as well since it's `ST_MakeValid` result was a polygon. Thanks!